# Compare 2 csv files using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can i compare 2 csv files using Pandas?

File1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
6
```

File2:

```
4
5
6
1
```

Expected result in another file:

```
2
3
```

Comment: Read the two csv, then check out `isin`: `df1[~df1['col'].isin(df2['col'])]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang This will give the matching results.

Comment: No, note the negate operator `~`.

Comment: import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv (
    'a.csv',
    header = None, usecols= [0]
)

df2 = pd.read_csv(
    'b.csv',
    header=None
)

print(df1[~df1[0].isin(df2[0])])

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to calculate the differences between the different csv files. Remember to change the file names to the name of your file.
Try this:

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

You could also use a more complex method using sets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import argparse
import csv


def get_dataset(f):
    return set(map(tuple, csv.reader(f)))


def main(f1, f2, outfile, sorting_column):
    set1 = get_dataset(f1)
    set2 = get_dataset(f2)
    different = set1 ^ set2

    output = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in sorted(different, key=lambda x: x[sorting_column], reverse=True):
        output.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs=2, type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'), default=sys.stdout)
    parser.add_argument('-sc', '--sorting-column', nargs='?', type=int, default=0)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(*args.infile, args.outfile, args.sorting_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `pandas`:

`pip install pandas`

Read both files in `pandas`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame('file1.csv', columns=['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame('file2.csv', columns=['a'])
```

Use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
In [430]: import numpy as np

In [431]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.setdiff1d(df1['a'], df2['a']))

In [431]: df
Out[431]: 
   0
0  2
1  3
```